# Can't run a command from Dockerfile or Docker Compose

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to create a nginx-laravel-mysql stack of docker containers using [laradock][1], a free docker-compose plugin for laravel.

To make it work, I have to run `php artisan key:generate` either from my local environment, or from within a running container (both bad practices).

I tried adding `command: /bin/bash -c "php artisan key:generate"` to my docker-compose.yml file.  This causes an exit; when I run `docker-compose ps`, I see `laradock_workspace_1        /bin/bash -c nohup php art ...   Exit 1`.  Adding `nohup` causes the same result.  **In fact, any command I run here causes an exit**

On to the Dockerfile.  If I add `RUN php artisan key:generate` (or any variation of it), I get this:

```
ERROR: Service 'workspace' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c php artisan key:generate' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

If I run that same command as `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT`, even with `nohup`, it runs and generates the key, but exits:

`docker-compose ps` says: `laradock_workspace_1   /bin/sh -c nohup php artis... Exit 0`

I can add `restart: always` to docker-compose.yml, but that begets a vicious cycles of key generate, exit, restart.

Any ideas how to execute this command (or any command) from Dockerfile or docker-compose.yml without exiting?

EDIT: to answer @dnephin's question: `php artisan key:generate` adds a hash to the /.env file and adds a value to a php array.  It just takes that command, no input.  When I run `docker-compose run workspace php artisan key:generate`, I get `Could not open input file: artisan`.

Strangely, when I run `docker-compose run workspace pwd`, I see the correct path to my laravel files (and I can see all of them if I run `docker-compose exec workspace bash`, but when I try to run `docker-compose run workspace ls`, I see nothing.  It's like the files aren't there.

Comment: What does `php artisan key:generate` do? If it requires a tty or user input that would explain why it's failing to run in the `Dockerfile`.  If you're trying to run a short-lived process to generate a key, you might need to do `docker-compose run workspace php artisan key:generate` instead of running `docker-compose up`

Comment: Up the containers `docker-compose up -d nginx mysql` then goto workspace container using `docker exec -it {workspace-container-id} bash` and finally run your `php artisan key:generate` command and see

Comment: @SauminiNavaratnam That does work.  I'm trying to avoid that though, I'd like to have a single script that you run from outside the containers.  I feel like that should be feasible.

Comment: @dnephin Edited with the results of your suggestion, see OP.